# Get image to scale responsively to the same size as text

Tags: css, liquid

I'm working on a Shopify site right now and I want the image to scale at the same size of the text. Currently it looks like this:
[Image of how the image is larger than the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnCs2.png)

This is the code that I'm using.

```
<div class="bulky-img-section-right">
{%else%}
<div class="bulky-img-section">
{%endif%}
    <div class="image-sub-section">
        <img class="is-image" src="{{section.settings.image-link | img_url:'master'}}" alt="{{section.settings.image-link}}" />
    </div></div>
```

CSS

```
    .bulky-img-section
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    width: 100%;

}

.bulky-img-section-right
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;

    width: 100%;
}

.image-sub-section
{
    width: 50%;
    
    padding: 3rem;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with some absolute position, only way I can think to remove the image from the normal flow.

```css
:root {
  --imageGap: 3rem;
  --imageSize: calc( 50% - var(--imageGap) );
}

.bulky-img-section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: var(--imageGap);
}
.bulky-img-section:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: var(--imageGap) }

.image-sub-section {
  position: relative;
  max-width: var(--imageSize); min-width: var(--imageSize);
}
.image-sub-section .is-image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.right .text-sub-section { order: -1 }
```

```html
<div class="bulky-img-section">
  <div class="image-sub-section">
    <img class="is-image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/1000" alt="Some random picture" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-sub-section">
    <p>Eros nisi mi nec natoque erat egestas pharetra dui eu interdum vestibulum est porttitor consectetur a lectus parturient justo fringilla dis a eros dui torquent curabitur molestie dignissim. Ac vestibulum suspendisse a enim tempus accumsan vestibulum nam proin parturient nunc suspendisse adipiscing lacinia a gravida tellus ridiculus a ac at etiam fringilla parturient quis malesuada sociis neque. Ultrices arcu blandit id vestibulum suspendisse a etiam a non condimentum facilisis senectus dapibus suspendisse curae. Ligula parturient mollis natoque a a mauris turpis nec dis dui rutrum suspendisse ad eget mus a sodales blandit.</p>
    <p>Gravida scelerisque neque magnis parturient commodo parturient nostra duis a ullamcorper a orci elementum nec mus bibendum justo a. Purus iaculis cubilia pharetra egestas orci rutrum auctor a ut elit himenaeos fames sociosqu eu sed a a senectus aliquet. Rhoncus aliquam erat a nibh nibh mollis suspendisse dui a risus elit nunc dictum a. Aenean integer orci arcu erat varius inceptos pulvinar condimentum etiam mauris purus dui consequat id ipsum odio semper blandit. Vulputate eleifend venenatis ridiculus metus massa non a sed et nunc dolor potenti adipiscing per cras natoque a fermentum ac varius vehicula a a quam vulputate blandit cum. Ad ullamcorper auctor a nam urna phasellus parturient a vestibulum elit fermentum mi dictumst a consectetur nisi id fames.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bulky-img-section right">
  <div class="image-sub-section">
    <img class="is-image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/1000" alt="Some random picture" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-sub-section">
    <p>Eros nisi mi nec natoque erat egestas pharetra dui eu interdum vestibulum est porttitor consectetur a lectus parturient justo fringilla dis a eros dui torquent curabitur molestie dignissim. Ac vestibulum suspendisse a enim tempus accumsan vestibulum nam proin parturient nunc suspendisse adipiscing lacinia a gravida tellus ridiculus a ac at etiam fringilla parturient quis malesuada sociis neque. Ultrices arcu blandit id vestibulum suspendisse a etiam a non condimentum facilisis senectus dapibus suspendisse curae. Ligula parturient mollis natoque a a mauris turpis nec dis dui rutrum suspendisse ad eget mus a sodales blandit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```